Issue With JavaScript "change" not picking up a drop down menu selection
I am populating a dropdown menu and when the user selects a choice from the menu I want a function(pullWeights) to happen.  I cannot figure out where my error is, I have added an echo statement to error check and my code isnt making it into the addEventListener section where the echo command is. In a browser when I view this page I see the drop down box and everything looks correct with it, but when I choose an option from the dropdown box nothing happens(It doesnt look like im making it into the actual function) Im sorry in advance if I asked this incorrectly, its been a long time since I have used StackOverflow.  Here is the code where my problem is happening:
    <label for="licensetag">Choose A Reptile ID:</label>
    <select name="license" id="license">
        <?php foreach ($ReptileID as $ReptileID): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $ReptileID; ?>">
                <?php echo $ReptileID; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <script>
    const dropdown = document.getElementById("license");
    dropdown.addEventListener("change", function() {
        const selectedValue = dropdown.value;
        console.log("Selected value:", selectedValue);
        <?php echo "selectedValue"; ?>
        // Do something with the selected value, e.g., pass it to a function
        pullWeights(selectedValue);
    });
    </script>


"my code isnt making it into the addEventListener section where the echo command is" - That echo operation doesn't make any sense, why are you emitting a literal string to JavaScript code like that?  What is the resulting JavaScript code here?  Is that code producing an error on the browser console?  If not, what other debugging have you done in the browser's development tools?

By "my code isnt making it into the addEventListener section" do you mean the script isn't in the browser source code? Or the script isn't being executed?

@David that was my attempt at printing something to the screen to see if Im actually making it into that block of code.  I am a total novice when it comes to programming, learning as I go.

@mykaf when i load the page up in a browser, nothing happens when i choose an option from the drop down menu.  Im assuming that im not making it into the addEventListener block of code

@Brandon: How would emitting that string to the JavaScript code confirm whether that JavaScript code is working?  You may be fundamentally misunderstanding a few things here, including the difference between client-side code and server-side code.  Have you examined the page source to see if that value is where you echo it?  Have you opened the browser's development/debugging tools to check for errors on the console?  What specific indication do you have that something isn't working and what investigation have you done?

Make sure you have full error reporting and error display/logging turned on. It might help you to view the page's source on render, and not just the inspect, you should look at what was literally transported over HTTP. It is rare to have a PHP+JS problem. Once you PHP has sent everything, unless your JS is making a server-side call you'll have an HTML+JS problem usually. Your PHP might however, be writing bad HTML or JS, and that's what view source is for.

I noticed just some little problems (in my opinion) with the code.
If the JavaScript is generated by a PHP script (which I think is the case in the example), this line:
<?php echo "selectedValue"; ?>

Will be parsed as this line in JavaScript:
selectedValue

Which will effectively do nothing.
The output script is like this:
<script>
    const dropdown = document.getElementById("license");
    dropdown.addEventListener("change", function() {
        const selectedValue = dropdown.value;
        console.log("Selected value:", selectedValue);
        selectedValue
        // Do something with the selected value, e.g., pass it to a function
        pullWeights(selectedValue);
    });
</script>

Then, if this resulting code is not working (please, see if there's any console errors), then it's probably because there's no pullWeights function.
Here's my working example (changed PHP with JavaScript):


<script>
const options =
[
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Option 1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'Option 2',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'Option 3',
  },
];
</script>

<label for="licensetag">Choose A Reptile ID:</label>
<select name="license" id="license">
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <script>
    for ( const item of options )
    {
      document.write(`<option value="${item.id}">${item.text}</option>`);
    }
  </script>
</select>

<script>
const dropdown = document.getElementById("license");
dropdown.addEventListener("change", changeEvent =>
{
  const selectedOption = changeEvent.target.querySelector('[value="'+changeEvent.target.value+'"]');
  const selectedValue = selectedOption.value;
  const selectedText = selectedOption.textContent;
  
  console.log("Selected:", {id: selectedValue, text: selectedText});
  
  // Do something with the selected value, e.g., pass it to a function
  pullWeights(selectedValue);
});

// mocked
function pullWeights ( value )
{
  console.log('Pulling weights:', value);
}
</script>



Note that I slightly changed the event listener (there's no need to do that) and just mocked the pullWeights function.
Also, if the JavaScript is not generated by a PHP script, then it will produce error in the line with PHP tag that will make that JavaScript tag to not evaluate at all, in which case the event listener will not be attached to the dropdown.

As it relates to your note on the foreach, your example uses both $SomeReptileID and $TheReptileID which could confuse people. I'd also add that although it makes things much harder to read and debug, and should thus be avoided, naming the inner variable the same as iterated thing actually works: https://3v4l.org/3S7nA
